# How to count "if" dataGridView column is not empty

Tags: c#

I created dataGridView and set columncount into it. And gives first column name and width. But other 11 column got no name and width. I wanna count how many got a name?

```
        dataGridViewStats.ColumnCount = 12;
        dataGridViewStats.Columns[0].Name = "Date";
        dataGridViewStats.Columns[0].Width = 150;
        int i = dataGridViewStats.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
```

Int i gets only visible column count. But i wanna make it 1 and i got other method that adds column into it. WHen its added to our datagridview int i gonna go 2. How to do it?

Comment: You can sum i when you add a column. Or you can put an eventhandler on your datagrid to check i everytime the columns change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView's `Columns`'s type is a [DataGridViewColumnCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection?view=netcore-3.1).

This class implements the `IEnumerable` interface, so you can use most of the Linq queries.

If you need to count those columns where the name is not empty then you can use the following query:

```cs
dataGridViewStats.Columns.Count(column => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(column.Name));
```